# In what issue was Barack Obama the only dissenting vote

Tags: united-states, voting-systems, barack-obama

I think I heard somewhere that there was a vote in the senate where Barack Obama was the only dissenting vote.

I believe it was a vote to validate a war action.

This would be when Obama was a senator.

Does anyone know of such a senate vote?

Comment: Is this about when Obama was in the senate?

Answer (score 9):

I believe this was referring to a vote when he was a State Senator.

The bill was "[Born Alive Infant Protection Act](http://www.thepublicdiscourse.com/2008/10/282/)", which was a bill directing that live infants resulting from botched abortions are to be provided medical care (including comfort care to non-viable ones).

However, this was a complicated issue (in short, you can't say "Obama was the only dissenting vote"):

- The Federal bill was **unanimously** voted "for" by US Senate
- Since the federal bill didn't apply to the states, individual state legislatures introduced matching bills, IL including.
- Obama bitterly opposed the IL State bill and took leadership and extra personal effort to defeat it, including:

  - "no" votes in both Committee voting for 1 year
  - "no votes in floor voting" for 2 years
  - More importantly, extensively arguing against it on the floor debates
  - Even more importantly, on the 3rd year he simply stopped it from even being voted on by the Committee as Chairman.

---

- The above means that technically speaking "was the only dissenting vote" is incorrect:

  1. Obama was NOT the only "No" vote against that State senate bill in IL.
  2. But, this opposition **did put him in dissent to 100% of US Senators' position at the time** (though he wasn't a US Senator himself yet).

Obamas votes and opposition speech transcripts can be found [here (pretty partisan site but the links are to State Senate PDFs)](http://obamawantsyou.com/abortionsanction.html).

Comment: Nice detective work.  That's definitely not what I would have expected from the question.

Comment: Just as FYI - there may have been a US Senate bill too. But my Google-fu so far failed to find it

Comment: one problem that this answer has it that you don't even mention what the bill was until the last third of the answer.

Comment: @DVK I haven't voted on the answer yet, but I was just saying, you'd be wondering that "the bill" was while reading the majority of the answer.

Comment: @DVK - I had the same thought as Sam when I first read it: "But what was the bill?".  It's much better written now.